# Does $f_n=x^n$ on $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ...\}$ have a subsequence converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis

I know we can show $f_n=x^n$ on $[0, 1]$ does not have a subsequence converges uniformly by contradiction. But what if I define $f_n$ on $[1, 1/2, 1/3, ...].$ Does the conclusion still hold? If so, what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: $f_n$ does converge uniformly on $\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$, and even on $[0,1/2]\cup\{1\}$.

Comment: So it must have a subsequence converges uniformly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: On $[0,1-\delta]\cup\{1\}$ for any $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 0):

As @AnginaSeng suggests, $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly to the function $f : \left\{1, \frac12, \frac13, \ldots\right\} \to \Bbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &\text{ if } x = 1\\ 0, &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Indeed, we have
$$\|f_n - f\|_\infty = \sup_{k\in\Bbb{N}} \left|f_n\left(\frac1k\right) - f\left(\frac1k\right)\right| = \sup_{k\ge 2} \frac1{k^n} = \frac1{2^n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$
so $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\left\{\frac1k : k \in \Bbb{N}\right\}$.